# Is the mobile site truncating tags?

Tags: bug

[What is an elegant way to serve whole duck livers?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23632/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-serve-whole-duck-livers)  (please review the edit page)

On the first post, the tag "appetizer" was truncated to **appetiz**.  On edit, it was truncated to **appe**

I was posting from IE on WP 7.5.

Comment: Was your phone trying to autocomplete it, or had you actually typed out the whole word "appetizer" before you posted? I've only seen this happen when the SE site shows you a list of matching tags but you don't actually select one, or when my iPad has tried and failed to autocomplete a word for me.

Comment: The phone auto-completed offering me Appetite, Appetizer and Appetizers.  I touched appetizer(from phone AC), and then submitted.